# Polite terms for excrement

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, cortesía, vocabulario

There are many vulgar terms for excrement, but what are the non-vulgar, polite ones (used in medical settings, or with children, or among adults in polite conversation)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All of these terms are quite "polite":

- **Excremento**
- **Heces** (the singular is hez, but it's used in plural for this meaning)
- **Deposición** (very formal, used by the medical profession)
- **Deyección** (very formal, so much that some people wouldn't know its meaning; used by the medical profession)
- **Defecación** (very formal, used in medical environments)
- **Materia fecal** (very formal, used in clinical tests)
- **Caca** (not so polite as the others, but probably the term used with children)
- **Popó** (more childish even than caca, term used with children)

Comment: +1  "defecación" is common for polite use (not very formal, just formal) but it's more used for the act than for the product. "excremento" is preferred. And "caca" is slightly childish/informal, but not vulgar.

Comment: For a bit of laugh, let me add the funny, vulgar term for human defecation: "Mierda".